# Find nodes that have similar neighbors

Tags: database, neo4j

I am very new to Neo4j Database. Currently I am trying to find out the nodes that have similar neighbors. So for example, if there are five nodes `A, B, C, D, E` in the graph. The neighbors of `A` is `[B, C, D ,E]` and the node `D` has neighbors `[B, C, A]`, then the pair `[A,D]` is what I am looking for because they have `[B, C]` in common neighbors, the percentage is `SIZE([B,C]) / SIZE (MIN([B, C, A]))` which is `2/3`. I am trying to do this based on a threshold (`2/3` in this case).

There are two libraries: one is  ***apoc.coll.intersection***, and the other is ***algo.similarity.overlap***, but I failed to come up with a way to use those libraries...

Please help :(

Comment: What do you mean by `MIN([B, C, A])`?

Comment: Try adding some sample code to your question, to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Did you mean ```MIN(SIZE ([B, C, A]), SIZE ([B, C, A,E]))``` in the denominator?

Answer (score 0):

I created your scenario:

```
`MERGE (a:Alpha {name: "A"})
MERGE (a1:Alpha {name: "B"})
MERGE (a2:Alpha {name: "C"})
MERGE (a3:Alpha {name: "D"})
MERGE (a4:Alpha {name: "E"})

MERGE (a)-[:CLOSE]->(a1)<-[:CLOSE]-(a3)
MERGE (a)-[:CLOSE]->(a2)<-[:CLOSE]-(a3)
MERGE (a)-[:CLOSE]->(a3)
MERGE (a)-[:CLOSE]->(a4)`
```

Ran the Jaccard similarity:

```
`MATCH (e1:Alpha)-[:CLOSE]-(p1:Alpha)
WITH e1, collect(id(p1)) AS p11
MATCH (e2:Alpha)-[:CLOSE]-(p2:Alpha) WHERE e1 <> e2
WITH e1, p11, e2, collect(id(p2)) AS p21
RETURN e1.Name as from, e2.Name as to,
algo.similarity.jaccard(p1entity_type, p2entity_type) AS 
similarity ORDER BY similarity DESC;`
```

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ukgA.png)

For simpler explanation of Jaccard Similarity check this link:

https://community.neo4j.com/t/using-jaccard-similarity-in-enterprise-architecture-to-define-logical-components-of-domains/7160